# Send data to a InfoWindow of GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I want to send some data for the *Snippet* of an *InfoWindow* (the dialog of the Marker), but the class *MarkerOptions* defines only the method **.snippet(String)** for setting the text of the window's body

Now i use this escamotage:

```
    map.addMarker( 
    new MarkerOptions()
        .title(title)
        .snippet(m.getID() + " " + m.getVel().toString() + " " + m.getTime() + " " + color));
```

[...]

```
   String[] s = marker.getSnippet().split(" ");
   id = s[0];           
   vel = s[1];
   time = s[2];
   color = s[3];
```

but is not a great solution.

Can i send data in others mode?
Can i redefine and costumize a MarkerOptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Gson Lib, and convert you Object to json and set the json in snippet, and while parsing you can convert that json to object directly, that the best solution

Comment: I'd like this solution

Answer (score 1):

> Can i send data in others mode?

Yes. The usual way is to use

```
    private Map<Marker, YourModel> markerToModelMapping;
```

and when adding marker, putting it also inside this map.

Then later in `GoogleMap` callbacks:

```
    YourModel data = markerToModelMapping.get(marker_method_param);
```

You may also try [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/), which adds `Marker.getData` and `Marker.setData` methods, so you can assign any object to `Marker` directly without using `Map`.

> Can i redefine and costumize a MarkerOptions?

No.

Answer (score 0):

> Author's final solution (extracted from question edit):

Send the marker as JSon:

```
String Json = new Gson().toJson(myMarkerInfo);
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().snippet(Json));
```

Retrieve the JSon :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); 
MarkerInfo m = gson.fromJson(marker.getSnippet(), MarkerInfo.class);
```